# Add cash on delivery price while creating the order programatically in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a module which create order in magento. Everything is working fine. Now i want to add cash on delivery price to the order. When i create the order by magento default module it add a row in the Order Totals column in order details page in admin panel. I am able to find the cash on delivery price set by admin and add this to Grand Total. But currently it is not showing that additional amount is for Cash on Delivery.  Can any one tell me the function which add this option in admin panel order details page.

I found it show COD Fee when there is a value in cod_fee column of sales_flat_order table. Is there any function which insert cod_fee value.

Comment: Magento do not allow charging on Payment but there is way work around, For reference see this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payment-method-charge.html

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar the default magento module is providing this functionality. When i create the order by magento default module it add a row in the Order Totals column in order details page in admin panel. I just want to know how the magento do that. Is their any function available for this.

Comment: so your question something different. Rather price on Cash On Delivery method, you want save order where payment method is Cash On Delivery?

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar Order is saved successfully. And it also show the payment method as Cash On Delivery but not add the COD price in Grand Total.

Comment: May be you are using custom module to charge fee for Payment Module in that case.

Comment: it calls onepagecheckout/index/updateCheckout/ module to add COD rate to Grand Total and a row shows COD rate. But i am not able to understand code inside this method.

Comment: onepagecheckout is not default Magento module.

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar Yes i have create the module for it. And want to know about function which add COD rate to Order.

Comment: onepagecheckout is used for web site. And I create a module for Web Service for Android App. Web site module is working fine. This problem comes when i create order using my custom module.

Comment: You must have some other module that allow charging on Payment Method, do you?

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar when i create order from web site then it add COD charges to Grand Total. I think it must have the charging on Payment Module. I just want to know the function which add it to order.

Answer (score 0):

I found cod_fee is custom column in sales_flat_order table. I am not able to find any function or way to insert data into this column while creating order. So I update the row after the order created. Code i used for this is

```
if($paymentMethodId == "cashondelivery") {
            $data = array('cod_fee'=>$cashOnDeliveryRate,'base_cod_fee' => $cashOnDeliveryRate);
            $myOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($reservedOrderId);
            $myOrder->addData($data);
            try {
                $myOrder->save();

            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```